# Matrix with linear transformation with reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, reflection

Find the matrix of the linear transformation A which is the reflection in the line $y = \sqrt{2}x$ with respect to the standard basis in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

I Have no idea how to approach this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rotate the co-ordinate system anti-clockwise through $\arctan \sqrt{2}$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{pmatrix} =
\frac1{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \sqrt{2} \\ -\sqrt{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
now reflect in $x'$-axis
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x'' \\ y''
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
finally, return to original coordinates:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x''' \\ y'''
\end{pmatrix} =
\frac1{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & - \sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x'' \\ y''
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
altogether:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x''' \\ y'''
\end{pmatrix} =
\frac1{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & - \sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \sqrt{2} \\ -\sqrt{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix} \\
=\frac 13
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &  2\sqrt{2} \\
2\sqrt{2} & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: why did you do arctan to rotate it?

Comment: this angle brings the x-axis to co-incide with the line $y=\sqrt{2}x$

Answer (score 0):

The  image of $(1,0)$ when reflected through the given line becomes $(-1/3,2\sqrt{2}/3)$  and for $(0,1)$ it becomes $(2\sqrt{2}/3,1/3)$ Take them as the columns of $A$

Comment: how did you get to this answer.

Comment: Using coordinate geometry try to find reflection of a point $(a,b)$ through $y=mx$

Answer (score 0):

Rather than give you the answer, I'll show you how to do this kind of problem in general. You have an easy description (and matrix) of your linear transformation on a specially chosen basis; transform that to standard.

Let $\mathcal B=[b_1,b_2]$ be a basis, where $b_1$ lies on that line and $b_2$ is orthogonal to it. Then on that basis the matrix of your linear transformation will be
$$
 A'=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now you need to do bas change to the standard basis, which is given by $A=BA'B^{-1}$ where $B$ is the matrix with as columns the coordinates of $b_1,b_2$ in the standard basis.

Multiplication by $B$ converts coordinates in the basis $\mathcal B$ into the coordinates of the same vector in the standard basis; therefore what $A=BA'B^{-1}v$ is doing is convert the standard coordinates of $v$ into its coordinates on$~\mathcal B$, then compute the linear transformation in those coordinates, which is easy ($A'$), and finally convert the result back to standard coordinates.

Note that you can scale $b_1,b_2$ freely, as long as the lie on the indicated lines. So you may choose $[b_1,b_2]$ to be orthonormal, which simplifies the computation of$~B^{-1}$ since it will be the transpose of$~B$; however this might give uglier entries of$~B$ to begin with. Usually I try to stick with rational coordinates if possible, but here the very definition of the line to reflect in makes it impossible. You should try what scaling works best.